# iOS Simple Counter App with multiple counters and data export?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a simple tallying / counter app for iOS that supports data export, and assigns dates to the different counts.  It should also support multiple counters with titles.

Does anyone know of an app like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Cosy Counter](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/cosy-counter/id554305575?mt=8), my new free App for the iPhone. You can manage unlimited different Counters. I intend to update it regularly to add features.

Comment: Thanks for making that app it's great.  I only wish the counter buttons were a bit bigger, but other than that, it's EXACTLY what I needed!  Thank you! :)

Comment: Any suggestions are very welcome, as I am working on the first update. Please tell me, which buttons should be bigger. Send me an email on http://www.cosycounter.com .

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [Clicker Counter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clicker-counter/id306921465?mt=8) for a simple tally counter and [Tally](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tally-quick-counter/id572051403?mt=8) for more options (like multiple lists, count up or down, etc). Both are free to use.